# "exec_prefix" command not found when building - what do I miss?

Tags: shell, centos, make

I am trying to build a piece of software called `rtpengine` from Github, installed all dependencies, started running make, but there are lines saying

```
/bin/sh: exec_prefix: command not found
```

amidst lines of compiling and other stuff. These might mean that I am building the software incorrectly.

The problem is, I don't get why there should be a problem with making that software, as there are no build problems reported by the community, thus it's me who is doing something wrong. I have discovered that `exec_prefix` might rely to using Python which was not explicitly installed, but `/bin/python` is present and the package is updated, also `exec_prefix` is listed as an environmental variable, and `env` does not report a thing named such. I have checked that I have installed all dependencies listed on the Github page for `rtpengine`

Environment:

- OS: CentOS 7 minimal install, updated, installed EPEL and `https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-7.noarch.rpm` repositories
- Hardware: VM (VMware)

Any other data I should provide to help resolving this issue?

Comment: Is that OK that you have CentOS7 and rpmfusion for CentOS 8?

Comment: @nobody Oh sorry, a typo, or rather, an unaltered copy-paste. In fact, a rpmfusion used was for 7, I replaced 8 for 7 when installing repository. Fixing the question now.

Comment: It is far from being uncommon that the build systems for projects are broken. My advice: debug by yourself. exec_prefix is often given by the user or the configure script. It is a variable. My guess is someone forgot to put a '&' before that variable in a script.